# Pasar datos de una actividad a otra Android

Tags: java, android, activity

Hola tengo este codigo para enviar datos de una acividad a otra pero me abre automaticamente la otra actividad. Lo que me gustaria saber es como abrir la actividad a la que pasamos los datos desde otra actividad por medio de un boton.

```
public void Registrar(View view) {
    String doc=txtCodigo.getText().toString();
    String nom=txtNombre.getText().toString();
    String presentacion=txtPresentacion.getText().toString();
    String cantidad=txtCantidad.getText().toString();
    Intent j = new Intent(this,Informe.class);
    if(btnRegistrar.isClickable()) {
        ArrayList<String> registro = new ArrayList<String>();
        registro.add(doc);
        registro.add(nom);
        registro.add(presentacion);
        registro.add(cantidad);
        j.putExtra("doc", txtCodigo.getText().toString());
        j.putExtra("nom", txtNombre.getText().toString());
        j.putExtra("presentacion", txtPresentacion.getText().toString());
        j.putExtra("cantidad", txtCantidad.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(RegistroRm.this, "Pasaron datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(j);
```

intente algo así pero me detiene la aplicación.

```
  public void Informe(View view) {
    Intent informe = new Intent(this,Informe.class);
    startActivity(informe);
}
```

Comment: De hecho por medio del intent es la manera correcta para pasar datos de un activity a otro. Sería bastante útil ver el log que te arroja cuando se detiene la aplicación.

Comment: Definitivamente se necesita que agregues el error que se muestra en el LogCat

Answer (score 1):

En la actividad actual pasas los datos mediante un Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtraActividad.class);
intent.putExtra("Clave", "Valor");
startActivity(intent);
```

Y en la actividad que iniciaste (OtraActividad.class) simplemente obtienes tu Intent y usas el nombre de la clave para obtener el valor, en este caso un String

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String valor = intent.getStringExtra("Clave");
```

Seria bueno que coloques la salida que te genera la app al detenerse

Por ultimo, si quieres pasar un ArrayList debes crear un modelo personalizado que implemente Parcelable

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde alcanzo a ver y dado que no pusiste ningun log de error quiero pensar que no te sale ningun error, esto es porque creo que lo estas haciendo de forma correcta pero te hace falta obtener los datos en la siguiente actividad con algo como:

```
// para obtener la intencion
Intent intent = getIntent();
// para obtener la informacion
String doc = intent.getExtra("doc");
```

Answer (score 0):

también puedes enviar datos por SharedPreferences.
//guardar los datos

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("IDvalue", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("MiDato", datos.toString());
        editor.apply();`
```

y para recuperar los datos:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPf = getPreferences("IDvalue", 0);
        String variable = sharedPf.getString("MiDato","null");
```